# Why is Eclipse's HTML viewer randomly showing previous output and an error?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat

Well, this video shows my problem best : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDeChV254Ck&feature=youtu.be

If I have a page that is proper/ok, everything works fine and as expected.

If I purposely induce an error (which I have been doing loads of whilst learning!), Eclipse doesn't show an error at all inline/red underline, and, when I try to run, it will either display an error (which I expect it should be doing every time), or it will randomly display the last successful build.

I can (remotely) understand the logic of alternating, maybe someone would want to see the previous output, but, this is just completely random - no logic at all, so, I just don't understand why it is happening.

Does anyone know what is going on?

edit - been able to recreate this on a brand new install. What is going on!?

Comment: What happens if you press the refresh button in your browser window? Is the behavior of that consistent?

Comment: @FrancisUpton It is happening in Chrome as well, it is random/cannot predict the pattern, but, it seems to be on average a minimum of 5 and a maximum of 10 times that the previous success page is shown to every one error.... so, I guess that this means it is a problem/setting with Tomcat and not Eclipse?

Comment: Yeah, seems like for some reason Tomcat is being inconsistent in how it serves the page with the error in it, maybe due to some caching on that end. You might want to try shutting down your Eclipse and looking at it with Chrome to take Eclipse totally out of the picture. I mean it could also be that somehow Eclipse is changing the files under Tomcat randomly, so this will test for that.

Comment: @FrancisUpton I am not really comfortable at the moment with running/configuring Tomcat, I am only just learning JSP/Java as it is... FYI, I haven't configured Tomcat in the slightest, During the debug/run step on Eclipse, it automatically downloaded Tomcat, so, any problem is with the config that Eclipse is using or in Tomcat itself :/ ... but, again, I haven't changed anything... will see if I can see anything obviously, but, I fear this is beyond me for now.

Comment: Look at the Tomcat server properties in your Preferences -> Servers -> Runtime (servers I think?) - there should be a directory there where Eclipse is putting the files. Look there and see if it makes sense.

Comment: @FrancisUpton :( I can't see anything that looks suspicious/special... I think this must be a bug :(